# Error in my SQL statement (UPSERT)

Tags: sql, ms-access, insert-update, upsert

I'm trying to do an `UPSERT` (since that's what it appears to be called) and I'm getting an error: `Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80040e14' Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ...`

```
UPDATE myTable
SET Field1='10', Field2='11'
WHERE Date = #06/05/2013#
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
INSERT INTO myTable
(Field1, Field2)
VALUES (10, 11)
END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is using T-SQL (SQL Server) syntax that Access SQL does not understand. The VBA equivalent would be:

```
Dim cdb As DAO.Database
Set cdb = CurrentDb
cdb.Execute "UPDATE myTable SET Field1='10', Field2='11' WHERE [Date] = #2013-06-05#", dbFailOnError
If cdb.RecordsAffected = 0 Then
    cdb.Execute "INSERT INTO myTable (Field1, Field2) VALUES ('10', '11')", dbFailOnError
End If
Set cdb = Nothing
```

Notes:

1. `Date` is a reserved word in Access, so you should specify the field name as `[Date]`.
2. Notice that the code uses the unambiguous date format `yyyy-mm-dd`. You should use that format any time you have a date literal enclosed in hash marks (`#`).
3. Note also that it fixes the type mismatch in your code: The UPDATE statement tried to update the fields as text, while the INSERT statement tried to insert them as numbers.

### Edit re: comment

The ADO equivalent of the above would be

```
conntemp.Execute "UPDATE myTable SET Field1='10', Field2='11' WHERE [Date] = #2013-06-05#", RecordsAffected
If RecordsAffected = 0 Then
    conntemp.Execute "INSERT INTO myTable (Field1, Field2) VALUES ('10', '11')"
End If
```

Comment: Here's my code currently, how do I implement it. I'll admit I'm relatively new to asp, but I've been learning on the fly.

Here is the code I have:
`set conntemp=server.createobject("adodb.connection")
conntemp.open "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=" & domainloc & "db\WaterSupply.mdb;"`

Comment: After I sorted through one more error, this fixed the problem. Thank you very much! Especially for the edited answer helping me out!