# IF EXISTS record in MS ACCESS

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2007

What is the MS Access version of this MS SQL Query?

MS SQL QUERY:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 = 1)
BEGIN

-- UPDATE QUERY

END
ELSE
BEGIN

-- INSERT QUERY

END
```

MS ACESS QUERY???

Thanks in advance! :o)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in my SQL statement (UPSERT)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948860/error-in-my-sql-statement-upsert)

Answer (score 1):

Access does not have stored procedures.  'If Exists' is T-SQL.  Access has queries, which are roughly equivalent to views in SQL Server.  If you were to use ADO to execute the Select statement, a record count of 0 would indicate that it doesn't exist.  ADO otherwise normally returns a -1 in the record count, indicating that there are an unknown number of records in the result set.  If you do a MOVELAST on the recordset, the record count will be updated to reflect the entire number of records.  If this is a large group, MOVELAST may take some time to execute.

Comment: Thank you! That's all I need to know. :o)

Answer (score 0):

Access does have VBA, which is kinda sorta like T-SQL. But the syntax & commands available are completely different. It's actually a derivative of Visual Basic.

An Access query can call a VBA function.

And VBA can execute queries. So, for your example:

```
Sub ProcessCode()
   Dim SQL As String
   Dim RS As Recordset
   SQL = "SELECT 1 FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 = 1"
   Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
   If Not RS.EOF Then
      'do what ever here
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Will user this for my reference. Thanks for this.